# Build apk fail with apktool

Tags: android, batch-file, build, apk, apktool

I have the contents of the BAT file:

```
java -jar apktool.jar b E:/Android/ANDROID_TOOLZ/Launcher2 E:/Android/ANDROID_TOOLZ/Launcher2/NewLauncher2.apk
pause
```

I get an error when you run

> W: Couldn't find sources

[image: error]

no file APK does not appear

What's my mistake?

apktool - the latest version
environment variables ANDROID SDK & JAVA have

IMAGE ERROR => http://rgho.st/6nMtp6kZM/image.png

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please attach image to your question because links can become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **ODEX** application files!